# Controlling Dynamixel servo wirelessly using Arduino Mega

Tags: serial

I am planning to control multiple Dynamixel servos (MX28T or MX-64T) wirelessly using Arduino Mega. Since this servo uses serial communication, I need an additional serial port to interface with Xbee module. Although it seems to be very common application controlling these servos wirelessly based on Arduino, I could't find any of them in web. I found the two very well constructed libraries.

https://code.google.com/p/slide-33/downloads/list. This library is for MX28T servo, which is the same servo I am trying to use, but it uses UNO;therefore, I cannot interface with Xbee.

http://www.pablogindel.com/informacion/the-arduinodynamixel-resource-page/. This library use UART1 (serial1) to interface with servo (AX-12) motors. Therefore, I can connect Xbee module to UART0. But, the problem is that this library is outdated and not compatible with MX64-T servo anymore.

So my question is here:

Is there any one who has experience in controlling Dynamixel MX24T, MX64T servo series using Xbee module simultaneously? If you have experience, please share with me.

Is it possible for Arduino Mega can interface with Xbee module using Serial1 (i.e., RX18 TX19)? If it can, I might be able to use the library1 without any modification.

Answer (score 1):

The 
["arduino mega + xbee pro shield"](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,93561.0.html)
thread describes how to tweak the xbee pro shield
so you can connect whichever Arduino Mega serial port you want to it
(Serial1: RX1 and TX1; or Serial3: RX3 and TX3, or etc.).

Brief summary:

- de-solder solder jumper 2 and solder jumper 3.
- flip the switch to "DLINE" (away from "UART")
- (Now the TX and RX pins on the xbee aren't actually connected to anything).
- Connect the TX on the xbee to any RX of your choice on the Arduino Mega (perhaps RX3).
- Connect the RX on the xbee to the TX of your choice on the Arduino Mega (perhaps TX3).

While I haven't used Dynamixel servos (yet),
I have used the Arduino Mega to communicate with other devices over several of its UART serial ports more-or-less simultaneously,
so I am confident that the Arduino Mega can control Dynamixel servos and communicate over Xbee modules simultaneously.